# What is this 5 petals blue wildflower?

Tags: identification, flowers, wildflowers

What is this 5 petals blue wildflower? Zone 7

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: “Zone 7” is about as nondescript as it gets. Please see  https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/872/for-id-questions-why-should-i-tell-where-in-the-world-a-plant-is-growing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plant in your photos is an annual wildflower commonly called "**borage**" or "**star flower**" of the "forget-me-not" family **Boraginaceae**. It's scientific name is ***Borago officinalis***. It is an edible plant as well. It originates from the Mediterranean region, but has naturalized elsewhere. Other helpful/descriptive information can be found at the Wikipedia links below.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borage

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boraginaceae

Answer (score 3):

This is borage (*[Borago officinalis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borage)*); it is an herb - the flowers taste sweet since there is a drop of nectar available. Some people say the leaves taste like cucumber but they are awfully hairy.

Edit: sometimes people float the flowers in summer drinks, but to do so is terribly spiffy and superfluous.

Comment: The cucumber flavour is most pronounced in young leaves - which are also less scruffy and better for the kitchen.

Comment: I hear it is used as filling for ravioli in some parts of Italy. @Stephie